# Error: Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag

Tags: next.js, app-router

> Error: Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag

I’ve used `revalidatePath(path);` in an app router project in a `'use client'`, a component without a header, and `'use server'`. Everytime I get

```
Error: Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag_[hash-here]
```

Using next 14.0.1

Comment: are you passing correct path? is the path dynamic path?

Comment: I am passing a specific path, like `/thing/123`

Answer (score 0):

create file called actions.ts to the /app/actions.ts ....put this example :

```
"use server";

import { revalidateTag } from "next/cache";

export default async function action() {
  revalidateTag("profile");
}
```

now just call the action and enjoy...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).